# Problem in integration of bar code scanner in android

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I want to do bar code scanner in android from the link zxing [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk)

But the problem is,it shows camera view but it can't scanning bar code image.I am not understand what is the problem is?Please guide me.

Is there any another procedure rather than above link?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I first started using ZXing.

You need to make sure you are requesting the correct barcode format when starting the ZXing activity.

When calling (based on the example)

```
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
```

I'm guessing you actually want to use

```
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
```

Ensure that you include the correct barcode formats as per the [`Intents.java`](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/Intents.java) file:

```
/**
 * By default, sending Scan.ACTION will decode all barcodes that we understand. However it
 * may be useful to limit scanning to certain formats. Use Intent.putExtra(MODE, value) with
 * one of the values below.
 *
 * Setting this is effectively shorthand for setting explicit formats with {@link #FORMATS}.
 * It is overridden by that setting.
 */
public static final String MODE = "SCAN_MODE";

/**
 * Decode only UPC and EAN barcodes. This is the right choice for shopping apps which get
 * prices, reviews, etc. for products.
 */
public static final String PRODUCT_MODE = "PRODUCT_MODE";

/**
 * Decode only 1D barcodes.
 */
public static final String ONE_D_MODE = "ONE_D_MODE";

/**
 * Decode only QR codes.
 */
public static final String QR_CODE_MODE = "QR_CODE_MODE";

/**
 * Decode only Data Matrix codes.
 */
public static final String DATA_MATRIX_MODE = "DATA_MATRIX_MODE";

/**
 * Comma-separated list of formats to scan for. The values must match the names of
 * {@link com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat}s, e.g. {@link com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat#EAN_13}.
 * Example: "EAN_13,EAN_8,QR_CODE"
 *
 * This overrides {@link #MODE}.
 */
```

Comment: thanks for quick response, actually i want to develop scanner application without using intent(ie i do not want to dowmload scanner apk from market).For this I have used zxing android (scanner)

Comment: So, you've integrated the ZXing source into your app? You still need to use the correct scan mode when you start the scanning activity. The `Intent` is just used to pass the necessary information to the activity so that it knows what to look for.

Comment: i haven't integrated the zxing scanner code.i want to develop bar code scanner for this i used zxing library.already i mentioned "it shows camera view but it can't scanning bar code image"

Comment: OK - so, like I said, you need to make sure you are asking it to scan the appropriate type of barcode. In my app, I used the default example which only looked for QR barcodes. It wasn't until I changed it to PRODUCT_MODE that it also scanned the normal stripe barcodes that most people are familiar with. Bottom line - either set the specific barcode types you want to scan, or remove the `intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");` line to force ZXing to scan all barcodes that it understands.